# Перенос структуры из си с полем массива заданного размера

Tags: c#, c, .net

Каким образом переносить такие структуры в которых содержатся следующие поля?

```
typedef struct AVPanScan {
    /**
     * id
     * - encoding: Set by user.
     * - decoding: Set by libavcodec.
     */
    int id;

    /**
     * width and height in 1/16 pel
     * - encoding: Set by user.
     * - decoding: Set by libavcodec.
     */
    int width;
    int height;

    /**
     * position of the top left corner in 1/16 pel for up to 3 fields/frames
     * - encoding: Set by user.
     * - decoding: Set by libavcodec.
     */
    int16_t position[3][2];
} AVPanScan;
```

Интересует поле `position[3][2]`. Приветствуется небезопасный контекст.

Подозреваю что правильным вариантом может стать после фиксированного размера на 6 элементов:

```
fixed short Position[6];
```

Но тогда не совсем ясно как обращаться к элементам как по индексу вида:

```
SomeStruct.Position[0][1]; // и т.д.
```

Comment: В каком смысле «переносить»? Вам нужна бинарная совместимость (тогда это проблема, т. к. memory layout структур в C не определён стандартом), или вам достаточно простого `class AVPanScan { Int32 id, width, height; Int16[,] position = new Int16[3, 2]; }`?

Comment: @VladD: Класс не подойдет, т.к. структуру необходимо будет передавать в неуправляемый код.

Comment: То есть вам нужен конкретный бинарный layout? Тогда опишите его в терминах размеров данных и их позиций: `int` в C может занимать любое количество байт. И между полями вполне может быть вставлен padding.

Comment: Похоже придется описывать все это дело на [taG:c++-cli]

Comment: Там та же проблема. На C# всё будет работать с FieldOffset, но смещения ж нужно знать.

Comment: @VladD: мне подумалось описать несколько классов, которые бы заполняли структуру, и возвращали указатель на нее в виде `IntPtr`. Хотя, да, попробую с оффсетами.

Comment: @VladD: А может ли помочь если я узнаю реальный размер структуры и укажу это дело в `StructLayout`?

Comment: Да, это будет шаг в нужном направлении. Сейчас набросаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно поле типа `fixed`. К сожалению, такие поля могут быть лишь одномерными массивами, поэтому для доступа по двойному индексу вам понадобится аксессор:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct AVPanScan
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public Int32 id;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public Int32 width;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public Int32 height;

    [FieldOffset(12)]
    private fixed Int16 flatPosition[6];

    public Int16 GetPosition(int i, int j) { return flatPosition[i * 2 + j]; }
    public void SetPosition(int i, int j, Int16 value) { flatPosition[i * 2 + j] = value; }
}
```

(В C# нету именованных индексаторов, поэтому пришлось использовать два метода.)

В правильности `FieldOffset`'ов не уверен, перепроверяйте!

Comment: Только тип должен быть не `byte` а `short`, оффсеты правильные, и размер структуры в памяти занимает 24 байта :)